# Выражения "много больше", "много хуже" и "сильно дешевле"

Tags: грамотная-речь, фразеология, выбор-слов

Часто встречаю выражения *много больше*, *много хуже* и *сильно дешевле*. Можно ли употреблять на письме или в устной речи такие выражения без *на*? Знакомый преподаватель русского языка и литературы считает, что таких выражений быть не может.

Answer (score 1):

Можно согласиться с преподавателем в части выражения "**сильно дешевле**": оно чисто разговорное (на грани просторечия) и на письме его лучше не употреблять (есть стандартные выражения *"гораздо дешевле"*, *"намного дешевле"* и формальное *"значительно дешевле"*).

"**Много больше**" - математический термин, это стандартное чтение одного из знаков *неравенства* (одна из величин много больше/меньше другой). Допустимо и расширительное, бытовое употребление такого выражения (особенно в сочетании с числами) наряду с "*гораздо больше*" и формальным "*значительно больше*". Выражение "(*характеристики, параметры чего-л.*) **много хуже**" принадлежит области технической фразеологии и означает, что по нескольким *количественным характеристикам* (возможно даже, часть которых *чем больше* количественно, *тем хуже*) один технический объект значительно уступает другому, либо значительно хуже ведёт себя под действием каких-то внешних факторов. Поэтому нет оснований утверждать, что таких выражений "в русском языке нет (или быть не должно)".

Answer (score 0):

Много больше (меньше, лучше, хуже, дороже, дешевле, чаще, реже и т.д.) — все эти выражения употребляются, причем не так уж редко. Пусть преподаватель заглянет хотя бы в Нацкорпус.

Comment: А не могли бы вы ответить на вопрос: "Можно ли употреблять на письме или в устной речи такие выражения без на?"

Comment: Естественно. Примеров навалом, причем без НА едва ли не больше.

Comment: Ну так было бы неплохо написать об этом в ответе, да и привести ссылки на готовые поисковые запросы тоже.